# Matplotlib multi-colored title

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am looking for a simple way to create a title for a figure in which some words have distinct colors. 
So far, I have been attempting to use:

```
fig.text(0.35,0.85,'Black text', color="black")
fig.text(0.45,0.85,'Red text', color="red")
```

The problem is that I have to establish the center character of the whole string and calculate the x-coordinates accordingly, which is time-consuming.

I wish I could write the whole string in one line of code; something like this:

```
fig.text(.5, .85, ['Black text', 'Red text'], color = ['black', 'red'])
```

Or if I could create a variable for each color of code and string them together under fig.text or plt.title, that would be great.

Any ideas?

Even a way to display the pixel coordinates of each word in an existing title would help with the method I'm currently using.

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/1.5.0/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/rainbow_text.html